# Como pegar dados de dois inputs sem usar form?

Tags: angularjs

Quero fazer algo como no Excel.
Tenho dois inputs e em cada um eu digito valores. Ao pressionar ENTER eu quero capturar os valores digitados, como posso fazer isso?
OBS: Estou usando Angular 1.

```
<div class="descontoPromo">
    <input class="form-control depro" type="text" name="descontoPromocional" ng-model="valor.descPromo" >
</div>
<div class="descontoFin">
    <input class="form-control defin" type="text" name="descontoFinanceiro" ng-model="valor.descFinan" >
</div>
```

Comment: Você poderia usar o ngModel para isso, pelo que entendi, você deve apenas usar os valores de `valor.descPromo` e `valor.descFinan`

Comment: Isso se eu usar uma chama de função num botão em uma form, mas não quero usar form, nem botão.

Comment: Você não quer botão, pois quer que a função seja chamada pelo enter, ou tem outro motivo? Pois se for pelo enter, da para colocar um botão oculto, e que tratar no Js para fazer o enter executar o clique do botão.

Comment: Exatamente, "não quer botão, pois quer que a função seja chamada pelo enter". E como fazer esse tratamento no JS para executar o botão?

Comment: publiquei a resposta com um exemplo de como fazer. eu lembrei que uso isso sem ter esse botão invisível. espero que tenha te ajudado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta capturar o evento keydown do `$document` do *AngularJs*, e chamar a função que você deseja que seja executada.

Demonstro como fazer isso com o código abaixo. tanto a função quanto o *eventListener* devem está no *controller* do html que você deseja executar a função pelo enter.

Desta forma não será necessário botão, ou até mesmo um form.

```
    function enter(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            suaFuncao()
        } 
    }

    $document[0].addEventListener("keydown", enter, false);
```

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigado.

Comment: Por que $document[0]?

Comment: no meu caso o @document estava me retornando um array com 1 item, por isso tive que fazer isso.